# Workaround for FF printing fieldset truncated to one page (bug 471015)

Tags: css, firefox, printing

When printing a document, Firefox truncate `<fieldset>` to one page. This mean that a form with a `<fieldset>` that would take more than one page in print can not be printed correctly. This is apparently a known bug tracked on bugzilla since 2008 (see[bug 471015](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=471015)).

Is there a workaround (CSS or other) that allow printing of a single `<fieldset>` on several pages ? (other than not using `<fieldset>`) ?

Comment: Not sure it'll be possible. I know you mentioned you wanted to use a `<fieldset>`, but would you be total against just using a `<div>` styled like a `<fieldset>`?

Comment: Possible but wouldn't be easy. + I would have to change `legend` for another element styled to look lige `legend`,...

Comment: I think it would be fairly easy. This bug is 3 years old, so i dont see many other options...

Comment: You just replace html and add a selector to your already existing fieldset style. Not so much work really it's  5 min task :)

Comment: Since the form are generated via formtastic gem (RoR), this actually means adding rules to change the default code. So it will most probably take more than 5 minutes.

Comment: @LapinLove404 Yeah I suspected you would say something like that.

Comment: Anyway, if there is no workaround, I'll eventually have to take the time for theses changes.

Comment: Better solutions are at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336586/printing-fieldsets-in-firefox

Answer (score 1):

Check out this jQuery hack I just wrote to solve this issue, figured I'd share even though I'm a year late.  You can change "printEnclosure" to an HTML tag I believe and the CSS at the end is obviously optional.

```
<div id="printEnclosure">
<fieldset>
<legend>TEST</legend>

Test Content goes here...
</fieldset>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function()
{
        $('#printEnclosure').find('fieldset').each(function(i)
        {
            $(this).replaceWith('<div id="convertedfieldset'+i+'">'+$(this).html()+'</div>');
            $('div#convertedfieldset'+i).css('display','inline').css('text-align','left');
        });
});
/* ]]> */
</script>
```