# Printing fieldsets in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, truncate, fieldset, print-css

I've been adding some new css to an existing project (using media="print") in the page header. It's going smooth and (for once!) IE is giving nice, expected results, but Firefox does not...

The problem is that I have a fieldset which contains a *lot* of fields, and Firefox completely refuses (even in the latest version) to allow a page break inside the fieldset. This means anything that doesn't fit on one page is lost...

I've found the bug acknowledged on the mozilla website which has been open for 3 years - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=471015 - but can't find any reasonable workaround...

Any suggestions before I look to remove fieldsets or similar?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: possible duplicate of [Workaround for FF printing fieldset truncated to one page (bug 471015)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469569/workaround-for-ff-printing-fieldset-truncated-to-one-page-bug-471015)

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate but these solutions are better.  Now the bug is 9 years old and it's still unresolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I guessed, it's still broken in the latest [Nightly](http://nightly.mozilla.org/).

You could try to do something similar to [IE Print Protector](http://www.iecss.com/print-protector/) (aka the [widely](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#html5inie) used [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)).

http://www.iecss.com/print-protector/#how-it-works

> To display elements correctly in print, IE Print Protector temporarily
>   replaces HTML5 elements with supported fallback elements (like div and
>   span) when you print. IE Print Protector also creates a special
>   stylesheet for these elements based on your existing styles; this
>   means you can safely style HTML5 elements by element name in links,
>   styles, @imports and @media. Immediately after, IE Print Protector
>   restores the original HTML5 element to the page, right where you left
>   it. Any references to those elements and any events on those elements
>   will remain intact.

Firefox [now supports](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=307258) `onbeforeprint`.

So, when `onbeforeprint` is fired, you could change the `fieldset`s for `div`s, or something.

I'm not sure how viable this is, and it sure sounds complicated.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input - I reckon I'm going to go for a change to the fieldset, forcing it to be a DIV instead... I wanted to get rid of them anyway :(

Comment: I'd probably do the same thing, to be honest. Who *really* cares if it's a `fieldset` or a `div`?

Comment: Yea, that's my feeling - I've redone the whole thing to use fieldset's only when correct, and grouped everything else using div's and h2's with some clever CSS to get it identical! Thanks for the input. I'll mark this as accepted.

Comment: I hope someone's going to bake this bug a cake for its 10th birthday.

Comment: @ben.tiberius.avery 2018 and it shows "Reported:10 years ago"...well...happy birthday!!!

Answer (score 8):

My JQuery solution for FF:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).bind('beforeprint', function(){
        $('fieldset').each(
            function(item)
            {
                $(this).replaceWith($('<div class="fieldset">' + this.innerHTML + '</div>'));
            }
        )
    });
    $(window).bind('afterprint', function(){
        $('.fieldset').each(
            function(item)
            {
                $(this).replaceWith($('<fieldset>' + this.innerHTML + '</fieldset>'));
            }
        )
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Very nice, it fires even when I open the print preview BUT it loses any attribute of the original fieldset tag: I have a *disabled* fieldset that becomes enabled after printing.

Comment: [Here is a JavaScript port](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76534433/1248177) so you don't have to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this jQuery hack I just wrote to solve this issue, figured I'd share even though I'm a bit late.  You can change "printEnclosure" to an HTML tag I believe and the CSS at the end is obviously optional.

```
<div id="printEnclosure">
<fieldset>
<legend>TEST</legend>

Test Content goes here...
</fieldset>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
$(document).ready(function()
{
        var i = 0;
        $('#printEnclosure').find('fieldset').each(function()
        {
            i++;
            $(this).replaceWith('<div id="convertedfieldset'+i+'">'+$(this).html()+'</div>');
            $('div#convertedfieldset'+i).css('display','inline').css('text-align','left');
        });
});
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since JQuery is not as common nowadays, here is a full JavaScript solution:

```js
window.onbeforeprint = event => {
    document.querySelectorAll('fieldset').forEach(item => {
        item.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", `<div class="fieldset">${item.innerHTML}</div>`);
        item.parentElement.removeChild(item);
    })
};

window.onafterprint = event => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.fieldset').forEach(item => {
        item.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", "<fieldset>" + item.innerHTML + "</fieldset>");
        item.parentElement.removeChild(item);
    })
};
```