# What is breaking my page when printing?

Tags: html, printing, page-break, page-break-inside

I have a questioner and I don't know why when printing it's creating a break before the first question.

[Live demo (link)](https://app.crm-imm.ro/crm-imm/linkuri/sondaj.php?id=67&company=Opticnet&cli=3297&hs=qg9scGGoKKRM44m1MpqvoQ)

[image]

Comment: Prints what you displayed in your question along with the first two questions for me.  Perhaps a local issue with your printer settings..?

Comment: I think it's a problem with Firefox. I've tried right now to print it with Chrome and there is no problem whatsoever. It can be resolved in Firefox though?

Comment: When I tried, I did so in Chrome as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing fieldsets in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336586/printing-fieldsets-in-firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by removing the fieldset container that you had everything wrapped in.. Having the fieldset element was causing all of the fields to get grouped together, and since they would not all fit on the first page, they were all being pushed to the second page.  By removing the fieldset element, I was able to get Firefox to print the first two questions on page 1 identically to Chrome.

It seems this is not a new problem with Firefox and fieldset not playing nice together as I found an old Bugzilla ticket from 2008 which has persisted and is still being commented on in 2014 [(link)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=471015)

If retaining the fieldset is important, I found a solution someone else came up with here [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14237116/1922144)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).bind('beforeprint', function(){
        $('fieldset').each(
            function(item)
            {
                $(this).replaceWith($('<div class="fieldset">' + this.innerHTML + '</div>'));
            }
        )
    });
    $(window).bind('afterprint', function(){
        $('.fieldset').each(
            function(item)
            {
                $(this).replaceWith($('<fieldset>' + this.innerHTML + '</fieldset>'));
            }
        )
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I've added `<style type="text/css" media="print">
    .control-group {page-break-inside: avoid;}
    .btn {display:none;}
    .btn-primary {display:none;}
    #footer {display:none;}
    .descriere {page-break-after: avoid;}
    body {background-color: white;}
</style>`. Now on Chrome is exactly what I wanted, but in Firefox is printing me just the first page(h4 + description) and 1 page of questions.

Comment: The content is not static. It will change if the creator of the survey will make, let's say, at the first question 10 bullets.

Comment: Deleting the fieldset resolved my problem. Thank you!