# When trying to print a large fieldset, Firefox truncates. Can I "disable" a div instead?

Tags: html

I need to use a `fieldset` to be able to disable inputs in a form, when a specific role is set. But, when I try to print the page (which is basically a large form) everything that fits on a single sheet of paper is printed, and the rest is truncated. [This is a known bug.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=471015)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14237116/42389) JQuery solution would work fine, except it feels dirty :')

When I change the `fieldset` to a `div`, which is a lot cleaner in my opinion, I can no longer disable the form....

Question: can I disable an element if it's not a `fieldset`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing fieldsets in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336586/printing-fieldsets-in-firefox)

Comment: Sadly, it does not... That link is mentioned in the question as well, it's where I found the jQuery workaround.